# Approximate value of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\ln(k)}{k^p},
$$
which is easily seen to converge if $p>1$. Numerical computations seems to reveal that, if $n\in\mathbb N$
$$
\left\lceil\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\ln(k)}{k^{1+10^{-n}}}\right\rceil=10^{2n}.
$$
Is there an easy way to prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition of $\zeta$ function, you have$$S_n = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\ln(k)}{k^{1+10^{-n}}}=- \zeta'\left( 1+\frac{1}{10^n}\right)$$

Moreover, the series of $\zeta'$ near $1$ is given by
$$\zeta'(s)=-\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \gamma_{k+1} (s-1)^{k} $$

where the $\gamma_k$ are [the Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants)

So
$$S_n = 10^{2n} + \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \gamma_{k+1} 10^{-nk} $$

and using the majoration $|\gamma_p| \leq \left( \frac{p}{e}\right)^p$, you can easily see that
$$0 < \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \gamma_{k+1} 10^{-nk}< 1$$

which shows that $$\left\lceil S_n \right\rceil = 10^{2n}$$

Comment: You mean the series without the ceiling, right? Do you have a reference for this identity?

Comment: @frog I edited !

Comment: This is a very nice answer, thank you very much!